# I am trying to get the name of the message sender using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am building a simple private chat app with laravel.

I have a messages table with a column : id/sender_id/receiver_id and body

Please tell me how can i get the name of message sender ?. i tried following Please give me solution.

Note :- Actually message receiver is not receiving name of message sender with message. when sender message sent the message to receiver so receiver is getting  the name of message receiver instead name of message sender.

[image]

[image]

**Controller**

```
               $conservation = Message::where(function ($q) {
                        $q->where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->orWhere('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id);
                })->where(function ($q) {
                    $q->where('sender_id', $this->selectedUser->id)
                      ->orWhere('receiver_id', $this->selectedUser->id);
                })->get();
```

**Message Model**

```
 public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'sender_id');
    }

    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'receiver_id');
    }
```

**User Table**

```
  public function receiver(){

        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }

    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }
```

**html view**

```
             @foreach ($conservation as $message)
              <div class="message-area p-3  ">
                <div class="date border-bottom text-center my-3"><span class="bg-white px-3"> 
                 </span>{{$message->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}</div>
                <div class="d-flex">
                     @if ($message->sender_id === Auth::user()->id)
                     <b><p>{{$message->receiver->full_name}}</p></b>
                    @else
                    <b><p>{{$message->sender->full_name}}</p></b>
                    @endif
                    <div class="message-text ms-3">
                    <div>{{$message->body}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**
First, you need to send receiver_id from client-side to your backend ($receiver_id).
Then this code will consider two conditions: 1) you are the receiver and looking at the sender's message page. 2) you are the sender and looking at the receiver's message page.

```
return Message::query()
        ->where('sender_id',  Auth::id())
        ->where('receiver_id',  $receiver_id)
        ->orWhere('receiver_id',  Auth::id())
        ->where('sender_id', $receiver_id)
        ->with('sender')
        ->with('receiver')
        ->get();
```

Then you need to add some If conditions based on the authenticated user id in your client code.

Comment: after this query facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work just fine.

```
Message::query()
->where('receiver_id', $user_id)
->with('sender')
->get();
```

If you want to optimize the query, you can have this

```
Message::query()
->where('receiver_id', $user_id)
->with('sender:id,first_name,last_name')
->get();
```

I assumed that you've `first_name`, `last_name` columns. If you don't have them, you can replace them with your name column/columns.

In my opinion, you should also paginate the messages for performance reasons. Getting all the messages like this can be pretty costly since there might be too many messages.